# Plotting additive points in pyplot?

Tags: python, matplotlib

Starting with a .csv with a format roughly like
`date, qualitative info, value`

I've tried to plot this value in pyplot but run into the issue where I have multiple values for the same date since I don't care about the qualitative info in the .csv.

Is there a way to either add the two values together during the plotting process
or to merge the lists of dicts in such a way where I can go from:

```
[{'interval_start_timestamp': '2021-04-13', 'leavers': 3}, {'interval_start_timestamp': '2021-04-13', 'leavers': 16}, {'interval_start_timestamp': '2021-04-14', 'leavers': 6}, {'interval_start_timestamp': '2021-04-14', 'leavers': 10}]
```

to:

```
[{'interval_start_timestamp': '2021-04-13', 'leavers': 19}, {'interval_start_timestamp': '2021-04-14', 'leavers': 16}]
```

keeping in mind that there are instances where a date is not repeated, is there a way to write it universally so that a new .csv in the same format would behave as desired?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data is in a bit of an awkward format, so I think it is best to format it to something easier to use and format it back later:

```
# loop over all dictionaries in the input list and reformat them
merged_dict = {} # use timestamps as keys, leavers as values
for dictionary in csv_dicts:
    timestamp = dictionary["interval_start_timestamp"]
    leavers = dictionary["leavers"]
    
    # check if a key already exists
    if dictionary["interval_start_timestamp"] in merged_dict:
        merged_dict[timestamp] += leavers
    else:
        merged_dict[timestamp] = leavers

# use the data for whatever you want
plt.plot(merged_dict.keys(), merged_dict.values())

# format back to the old format using list comprehension
reformatted_dict = [{"interval_start_timestamp": timestamp, "leavers": leavers}
                    for timestamp, leavers in merged_dict.items()]
```

This outputs a plot and the merged data:

[image: plot of example data]

```
>>> reformatted_dict
[{'interval_start_timestamp': '2021-04-13', 'leavers': 19}, {'interval_start_timestamp': '2021-04-14', 'leavers': 16}]
```

Comment: Thank you very much for the succinct information! My original solution spanned dozens of lines and failed to be universal to new .csv's that may be in the same format.

Answer (score 0):

You could group the entries in a dataframe and then go on with them as you please (e.g., create a csv) or use it with matplotlib directly.

```
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict([{'interval_start_timestamp': '2021-04-13', 'leavers': 3}, {'interval_start_timestamp': '2021-04-13', 'leavers': 16}, {'interval_start_timestamp': '2021-04-14', 'leavers': 6}, {'interval_start_timestamp': '2021-04-14', 'leavers': 10}])

df=df.groupby(by='interval_start_timestamp').sum()

print(df.to_csv())
```

Output:

```
interval_start_timestamp,leavers
2021-04-13,19
2021-04-14,16
```

Comment: pandas certainly looks amazing. I'll have to look into it so I understand more what's actually going on here but it's also a super elegant solution!